# Making a story appear on facebook when user likes my website

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, share

I want a user to press this like button [image]

and then for it to come up on their facebook that they like it. Currently when i press the like button nothing comes up on my Facebook whereas if i like something on another site it shows on my Facebook. This is my code for the facebook like button:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.RexRApps.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specifically tell Facebook to post something, it will only get more prominent if the user decides to add a comment too. The only thing you can do to make it more visible is to optimize the Open Graph Tags, check the URL in the debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.RexRApps.com

(see "Warnings That Should Be Fixed" and check the "Object Properties". You should also refresh the info by putting the URL in the debugger again after you changed the OG tags.

And here´s some info about Open Graph tags:

http://ogp.me/

You don´t have a single OG tag on your website, that´s probably the reason why Facebook does not publish it correctly.

Comment: its not visible at all though and there is no option to add a comment

Comment: you really have to add open graph tags, it´s pointless to use the like button without those tags. you cannot switch the comment box on, it will appear if everything is correct.

Comment: title, description, image, url. see the link i posted, it´s right on top ("The four required properties for every page are")